# Modelling house energy production using month as a variable

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to model the energy production of a set of houses for which data on temperature and daylight over 22 months is available. The data is arranged such as such:

```
Label   House   Year    Month   Temperature Daylight    EnergyProduction
0         1     2011     7        26.2       178.9           740
1         1     2011     8        25.8       169.7           731
```

and so forth, where the month is given as an integer from 1 to 12.

I'm attempting to use the `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` class and have noticed that including 'Month' as a variable in the regression seems to improve the mean absolute percentage error slightly.

I think this may be because Month, Temperature and Daylight are correlated but am not sure whether the regression is still valid as the value 'Month' is essentially an arbitrarily assigned number and does not reflect seasonal changes in temperature/daylight?

Comment: You see that because of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm attempting to model the production of the 23rd month given 22 given Temperature and Daylight, so in this case I think it makes sense to not remove Seasonality from my data?

Comment: I'm just saying that seasonality is the source of your issues, not that you should only work with seasonally adjusted data. If I were doing this, I would start with some kind of seasonal ARIMA model with exogenous predictors. There is a large literature on forecasting energy demand, so you might also look into other techniques.

Comment: Don't bother about variable correlation, RF models handle these very well. If your purpose is prediction, you must remove the year feature as any new year will be an extrapolation. You may benefit from making a new feature defined as days(or weeks or months) away from brightest day on your hemisphere. Lattitude is nice too. What are label? When predicting a given house, do you expect historical record on this house? In such case you should predict the house in 23rd month given any month and any data you have on the house, e.g. previous observed seasonal related energy productions

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Label is just an arbitrary data marker and does not contain any important information. I'm a bit confused, as you said I must remove the year feature, but I think past consumption pattern may be a big indicator of future consumption as well?